# Why do most arduino function return a -1 instead of a 0

Tags: library, functions

Many arduino functions return -1 if something 'fails'. Serial.read for example returns -1 or the infamous ÿ when this function is called while the serial buffer is empty.

As embedded C progammer, I am personally a fan of letting functions return data in the form of modifying pointers which points to passed on addresses and return states with the actual return functionality of a function. I am used to return a 0 if a function is 'not done' or 'failed'.

I see no logic in why many arduino functions return an int type which contains -1 instead of just a 0.

Would it not be better to let functions return a boolean type or an unsigned char type in which false or '0' would indicate a 'failed' process and true or '1' would indicate a 'succesful' process?

Also: if I type: 
`if(Serial.read()) {/* body */ }`
and `Serial.read()` returns -1 because the buffer is empty. Will the If's body be executed or not?

Comment: how would you return a byte with value 0 from read() if 0 would indicate error?

Comment: @Juraj I realized that ```Serial.read()``` was perhaps a very poor example as this function returns  both return values as a state (-1). Perhaps that ```Serial.begin()``` would be a better example

Answer (score 3):

I cannot assert anything for sure, as I was not involved in the design
of the Arduino APIs. However, just like Elliot Alderson, I suspect this
was inspired by the traditional C APIs. The manual page for `getchar()`,
which is a very old function from the standard C library, states:

> **fgetc**(),  **getc**() and **getchar**() return the character read
>   as an *unsigned char* cast to an *int* or **EOF** on end of file or
>   error.

Given that `EOF` is usually defined as `-1`, this is consistent with the
behavior of `Serial.read()`.

Being beginner-friendly is also a *major* goal of the API. Pointers are
known to be a *huge* difficulty for beginners.

There may also be some efficiency considerations involved. Arduino
started on the AVR platform. This is a RISC architecture, with a large
number of generic CPU registers (namely 32). The compiler usually
manages to allocate most local variables to registers. The calling
convention ensures that in most cases function parameters and return
values also go through CPU registers. This means we can avoid many RAM
accesses, which are inherently much slower than register access. Using a
return-by-pointer convention defeats these optimizations.

Lastly, it is a good thing that simple things are easy to write. For
example, an interpreter for single-character commands can be very easily
written as:

```cpp
switch (Serial.read()) {
case 'a':
    do_command_a();
    break;
case 'b':
    do_command_b();
    break;
// etc...
}
```

with no need to explicitly test for the serial buffer not being empty.
Obviously, a more complex command language will need a full-blown
interpreter, but the focus of Arduino has always been on *simple*
programs being easy to write.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino API is port of Processing. Processing is Java API to communicate with a MCU running Firmata. Arduino enabled sketches with the same API to run directly on the MCU.

So for example stream functions from Java stream classes were ported to Arduino API. This includes the [read() function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--), to read one byte. Of course Java and Java basic libraries have inspiration in C++.

For other read and write functions, if the return value is count of bytes written or read then 0 is a valid return value and -1 indicates error.

Processing, Wiring and Arduino were created by interactive arts teachers and students, not by embedded systems developers. So you can't wonder about not ideal data types used. Later some things were improved by software developers.

---

as embedded C developer you should know that:

- 0 is a valid value to read, so it can't be a value indicating error
- 'if' executes if the evaluated value is not 0

Comment: How does this answer the question? You didn't say anything about return values.

Comment: sorry, you are not familiar with the Java read function.. I added a link to JavaDoc of Java read() function. and I addressed the thought error of OP about the error return value of read() in a comment

Comment: In an Arduino forum I think you should assume that readers are not familiar with Java. Also, could you include the important information directly in your answer, just in case the link breaks some day?

Comment: So to get to the heart of the matter, can you explain why (if in fact it is true) Java functions return -1 instead of 1 (or `True`) for an error condition? I mean even those functions that are not returning a byte value, but only a pass/fail indication.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, that is explained in your answer :-). I have "inspired in C++", which is inspired in C...

Comment: if the return value is count of bytes written or read then 0 is a valid return value

Comment: I was unsure if ```if(something)``` would also be true, if something was signed AND negative. I hardly use signed value types at all.

Comment: Also, as 'embedded C developer' I do know that ```Serial.read()``` does not have to be interperted as a charachter. For all you know I use ```Serial.read()``` to read an array of numbers which also could contain 255

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this a legacy from Unix command programming, which was first done in C. For commands that only needed to return status and not data, a return value of zero meant success and any other return value indicated some kind of failure. Individual programmers could designate specific non-zero values for specific error types, if desired.

Remember that the return value comes back to the calling function in a register. And these days the term "Arduino" encompasses a broad range of architectures, including 32-bit ARM Cortex-M. Specifying that the return value is a char offers no advantage in this case.

The boolean datatype is a fairly recent addition to the C language, so it's not surprising that you don't see it used much in existing, portable libraries.

Returning an address from a simple function that just needs to indicate success or failure seems like overkill.

If you really want control over the datatypes, include `stdint.h` and use the types defined therein. If you want an unsigned 8-bit value use `uint8_t` and not `unsigned char`. If you want to allow the compiler to choose the best datatype that is at least 8 bits, use `uint_fast8_tf`.

Answer (score 0):

-1 is returned when "0" would be a perfectly valid response.

To take your example of `Serial.read()`: 0 is a valid byte or ASCII character.  -1 isn't.  If you returned 0 for "failure" then there would be no way of differentiating between that and the valid byte value 0.

Comment: Are you sure that the Serial.read() can not return binary values rather than just ASCII? I can't find that in the documentation.

Comment: What is ASCII? It is just shapes that humans have decided to associate with numbers. Everything is numbers. The numbers 0-255 - and we have decided that certain ones of those numbers will represent letters in our minds. Serial.read() returns the byte that is next in the receive buffer. That byte is 0-255, and if we want 65 to mean "A" then we can. But if there's no byte to return from the receive buffer then something "not a byte" must be returned to mean "there's nuffink there, bruv!", and -1 is not a byte.

Comment: Ah, so the missing bit of information is that we are assuming that an `int` is defined to be bigger than 8 bits, and the Serial.read() returns an `int` rather than a `char`. A `char` value of 0xFF could be a valid return value, but an `int` of 0xFFFF is not.

Comment: That's not an assumption. It's a cold hard fact. An int will always be bigger than a byte.

Comment: Agreed, given an ANSI compiler. I shouldn't have said "assuming" I should have said "recognizing".